# Listen to HBase table updates

Tags: java, hbase, database, nosql

How to keep a listener for my HBase table that notifies in case the table is updated (e.g. addition of new rows)?

This should be similar to a backend service running, which is possible for the mysql databases using hibernate.

Comment: You could write a Spark Streaming custom receiver / Flume agent to do this? Just curious, what did you finally do?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Hbase Co-Processors](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/02/getting-started-with-hbase.html), it provides the observers which can detect the change in table.

Best Explaination is given here https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction

Comment: Thanks. So do I need to write a prePut()?